# get status of the requested URL added in <script src > tag

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have to perform async execution, and i have wrote the below code

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = document.getElementById('<%= hdnScannerUrl.ClientID %>').value;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Now i need to know whats the status of src like 404, 200 etc.
Can i do that?

Note : i cannot use xmlhttprequest object or $.Ajax method, since they are not compatible with my request as they set the "referer" in the request header and the requested url (which is of device) will not response in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your module/logic inside the script is defined like this:

```
var module = {};
```

The when the onload event of the document is fired, you can check if the object exists.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (module) {
        //script loaded
    }
}
```

There are probably some other ways, but this seems the easiest

**UPDATE**

Here is another way:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = document.getElementById('<%= hdnScannerUrl.ClientID %>').value;
script.onload = function() { // note, use onreadystatechange for IE
    alert('i am loaded');
};

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```